# PDF.js : How to stop PDF turns into 180 Degree when using page navigation

Tags: pdf.js

I want to use PDF.js for loading PDF into viewer. While loading and navigating pdf pages. It gets turn into 180 Degree.

For example see this video : https://youtu.be/4w0276IFv58

For example see this demo  : http://testchat32.tk/PDF/

You can get all files used in page source.

Any suggestion or solution much appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: apply a CSS `transform: rotate(180deg);` ?

Comment: @jakub thanks, But actually i want to stop rotating which happens while using page navigation next - previous buttons. Plz check reference provided